# Avoiding loading whole blob to memory

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I store large files (50-500MB) in database. Once loaded by the application, it doesn't need the whole file in memory. How do i fetch table row (or specifically the installer from the row) directly into the memory while avoiding loading the entire file into ram (So a sort of a buffered download into file)?

I haven't found a solution that avoid loading the file so far. Instead i forward requests to flask server that loads the entire file, and then allows the application instance to download it into a file. However this doesn't seem like a very good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [FILESTREAM (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server):

> FILESTREAM enables SQL Server-based applications to store unstructured data, such as documents and images, on the file system. Applications can leverage the rich streaming APIs and performance of the file system and at the same time maintain transactional consistency between the unstructured data and corresponding structured data.

It is interesting because on SQL Server (for Windows) it can stream file data to Windows clients without having to load their entirety into the memory of the SQL Server:

> The Win32 streaming support works in the context of a SQL Server transaction. Within a transaction, you can use FILESTREAM functions to obtain a logical UNC file system path of a file. You then use the OpenSqlFilestream API to obtain a file handle. This handle can then be used by Win32 file streaming interfaces, such as ReadFile() and WriteFile(), to access and update the file by way of the file system.

Do note that at this time it is [not supported on SQL Server 2017 for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes?view=sql-server-2017#Unsupported).